# Will a PrintWriter without assignment to a variable close after using?

Tags: java, io, stream, printwriter, autocloseable

Is

```java
new PrintWriter(ExampleStream).print("Just Something");
```

same as

```java
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(ExampleStream);
pw.print("Just Something");
pw.close();
```

So will the PrintWriter close?

Comment: Why do you think it would?

Comment: May be because AutoCloseable? Im not really sure what this interface does.

Comment: This interface is useful for the try-with-resources statement. See here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: ok thank you for quick answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

And technically the term anonymous in Java refers to creating a local class without a name. What you did is just creating an instance of a class without assigning it to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

No, They both are not the same case

In the  second example  of your, question  PrintWritter will get close immediately the moment pw.close() will get executed. while

In the  first case of your question, printwriter will not get closed immediately.   After calling --> new PrintWriter(ExampleStream).print()
since you do not have any reference to its object thus you cannot use this same object again which means that it is eligible to be removed by garbage collector. As we cannot say when garbage collector will run that's why there is no certainty over when this object will be removed. one more important thing to keep in mind  is that even though this object  might be removed by garbage collector but that process is  not same as pw.close()